# UDP checksum calculation for checksum results in the value zero

Tags: ipv4, tcp, udp, layer4, checksum

I read UDP checksum from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol)  that "If the checksum calculation results in the value zero (all 16 bits 0) it should be sent as the one's complement (all 1s) as a zero-value checksum indicates no checksum has been calculated. In this case, any specific processing is not required at the receiver, because all 0s and all 1s are equal to zero in 1's complement arithmetic."

I don't understand when checksum calculation be zero in one's complement, but all 1's possible to get. My understanding Zero sum means there is no data to calculate. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UDP checksum value of zero indicates that the checksum option isn't used (checksum value is not to be verified). Therefore, a calculated checksum of zero is replaced by all ones to indicate that case unambiguously.

See [RFC 768](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768.html):

> If the computed  checksum  is zero,  it is transmitted  as all ones
> (the equivalent  in one's complement  arithmetic).   An all zero
> transmitted checksum  value means that the transmitter  generated  no
> checksum  (for debugging or for higher level protocols that don't
> care).